# Laravel - deleting collection

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am trying to delete a collection by using Laravel delete method. I am getting a collection from DB with this query:

```
$oldIssues = Issue::where('foldername', $paper['foldername'])->whereNotIn('title', $newIssues)->get();
```

And then I am deleting the images of those `$oldIssues` by doing this:

```
foreach ($oldIssues as $oldIssue) {
   File::delete(public_path('uploads/' . $oldIssue->image));
}
```

After that I am trying to delete those `$oldIssues` like so:

```
$oldIssues->delete();
```

I have read that is because I am using `get()` method in the query, how can I fix that, so that I can get the collection and then delete all the images of those `$oldIssues`?

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
$oldIssuesQuery = Issue::where('foldername', $paper['foldername'])
    ->whereNotIn('title', $newIssues);

$oldIssues = $oldIssuesQuery->get();

foreach ($oldIssues as $oldIssue) {
    File::delete(public_path('uploads/' . $oldIssue->image));
}

$oldIssuesQuery->delete();
```